# Return 2-D array from scipy Regular Grid Interpolator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm using Scipy to interpolate data in 6 dimensions, and would like a way to return a two dimensional array from my interpolator object instead of a one-D array. At the moment, I can only accomplish this by using a for loop and calling the interpolator object many times- I'm hoping there's a better method out there.

For example, in 3D:

```
#Random data
points=(np.arange(10), np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
values=np.random.rand(10, 5, 5)

interp_object=scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator(points, values)
```

I'd like to be able to do:

```
#Pick some points along each axis
x_points=np.arange(10)
y_points=[1.2, 3.1, 1.4, 4.8, 0.1]
z_points=3.5


xi=(x_points, y_points, z_points)

out_array=interp_object(xi)
```

But this leads to

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

and I have to end up doing:

```
out_array=np.empty((10, 5))
for i, y in enumerate(y_points):
    out_array[:, i]=interp_object((x_points, y, z_points))
```

This loop is the main bottleneck in my code and I'd like to avoid it if possible! Is what I'd like to do possible, using `RegularGridInterpolator` or another interpolation method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
#Pick some points along each axis
x_points=np.arange(10)
y_points=[1.2, 3.1, 1.4, 4.8, 0.1]
z_points=3.5

xi=(x_points, y_points, z_points)

out_array=interp_object(xi)
```

will not work, as you have to give the inputs as an array of all the points you want. So we need to generate a matrix with all the combinations. For this we can use `meshgrid`. We also need to include some manipulation with the array dimensions to get everything working, so it might look a bit messy. Below is an example:

```
#Pick some points along each axis
x_points = np.arange(9) + 0.5  # Points must be inside
y_points = np.array([1.2, 3.1, 1.4, 3.9, 0.1])
z_points = np.array([3.49])

points = np.meshgrid(x_points, y_points, z_points)
flat = np.array([m.flatten() for m in points])
out_array = interp_object(flat.T)
result = out_array.reshape(*points[0].shape)
```

Also notice I've changed the points you gave a bit. The `RegularGridInterpolator` can only be used for interpolation, and will not work if used outside the ranges given when creating the interpolation function, which is called `interp_object` in this case.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!